# SQL for summarizing data of the table

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following 3 tables:

1. Transaction Table

```
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------+----------------+------------+------------+
| Tran_id | Tran_seq_nbr | Tran_sold_amt | Card_no | Payment_Method | Card_type  | Tran_Date  |
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------+----------------+------------+------------+
| 1010    | 1            | 10            | 123     | Card           | Visa       | 2019-01-01 |
| 1010    | 2            | 20            | 124     | Card           | MasterCard | 2019-01-01 |
| 2020    | 1            | 30            | 125     | Card           | Visa       | 2019-01-31 |
| 2020    | 2            | 40            | null    | Cash           | Null       | 2019-01-31 |
| 10101   | 1            | 100           | 123     | Card           | Visa       | 2019-02-01 |
| 1011    | 1            | 100           | null    | Cash           | null       | 2019-02-01 |
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------+----------------+------------+------------+
```

2. Customer Table

```
+---------+-----------+
| Cust_id | Cust_name |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | Jane Doe  |
|       2 | John Doe  |
+---------+-----------+
```

3. Credit_card Table

```
+---------+---------+------------------+
| Card_no | Cust_id |    Card_type     |
+---------+---------+------------------+
|     123 |       1 | Visa             |
|     124 |       1 | MasterCard       |
|     125 |       2 | Visa             |
|     126 |       2 | MasterCard       |
|     127 |       3 | Visa             |
|     128 |       4 | American Express |
+---------+---------+------------------+
```

Write SQL queries for the following:

For each customer find out the expense that they have made through each card and cash within last one year. 
For Example:

SalesByCardPerCust

```
+---------+-----------+---------+--------------+---------------+
| Cust_id | Cust_name | Card_no |  Card_type   | Tran_sold_amt |
+---------+-----------+---------+--------------+---------------+
|       1 | Jane Doe  |     123 | Visa         |           110 |
|       1 | Jane Doe  |     124 | MasterCard   |            20 |
|       2 | John Doe  |     125 | Visa         |            30 |
|       2 | John Doe  |     125 | Cash_Payment |            40 |
+---------+-----------+---------+--------------+---------------+
```

I managed to get the data card wise but not able to get cash transactions.

The query I used is

```
    SELECT cu.cust_id
    ,cu.cust_name
    ,cr.card_no
    ,cr.card_type
    ,sum(tr.tran_sold_amt)
    FROM TRANSACTION tr
    INNER JOIN credit_card cr ON cr.card_no = tr.card_no
    INNER JOIN customer_table cu ON cu.cust_id = cr.cust_id
    GROUP BY tr.card_no
    ORDER BY cu.cust_name ASC;
```

Comment: you are joining on card_no and for cash transaction you don't have card_no, that's why data is not fetched for cash transaction. Try using left join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close to solution :)

```
SELECT cu.cust_id,
       cu.cust_name,
       tr.card_no,
       tr.card_type,
       tr.Payment_Method,
       sum(tr.tran_sold_amt)
FROM TRANSACTION tr
         INNER JOIN customer_table cu ON cu.cust_id = (
    SELECT cust_id
    FROM TRANSACTION tr2
             INNER JOIN credit_card cr2 ON tr2.Card_no = cr2.Card_No
    WHERE tr2.Tran_id = tr.Tran_id
    LIMIT 1
)
GROUP BY tr.Payment_Method, tr.card_no
ORDER BY cu.cust_name ASC;
```

should do the trick. You have to group by payment method first, then by card id.

Comment: here's a hint that i got for cash payment data linking If you look at the transaction table entries. Entries with the same tran_id are for transactions done by the same customer. Tran_seq_nbr gives the sequence of transactions done by that customer.
Also, if a cash payment can not be traced back to a customer then it's ok to drop that entry.

Comment: Then - it'll be not possible to join customer to transaction if it has just cash transactions. Best solution is to add customer_id to transaction table.

Comment: I edit my answer - this query will get results that you want, but only for customers that have at least one card transaction.

Comment: Thanks @lucek , this should solve the problem for now.